# MOTD is not being viewed completely

Tags: 14.04, ssh, motd

here is my problem. When I login via ssh as root to my ubuntu 14.04.2 VM I see this

```
[skynet]~> ssh gm-st01
Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS gm-st01.name.lab ssh-pty

No mail.
Last login: Fri May 15 16:23:02 2015 from skynet.name.lab
```

BUT

```
[gm-st01]~> run-parts /etc/update-motd.d/
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-52-generic x86_64)

                                 _    ___  _  
        __ _ _ __ ___        ___| |_ / _ \/ | 
       / _` | '_ ` _ \ _____/ __| __| | | | | 
      | (_| | | | | | |_____\__ \ |_| |_| | | 
       \__, |_| |_| |_|     |___/\__|\___/|_| 
       |___/                                  

  System information as of Fri May 15 16:34:23 AMT 2015

  System load:  0.0                Processes:           190
  Usage of /:   10.2% of 23.19GB   Users logged in:     1
  Memory usage: 1%                 IP address for p1p1: 10.24.20.129
  Swap usage:   0%
```

ALSO

```
[gm-st01]~>cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config
PrintMotd yes # with no everything is the same
PrintLastLog yes
TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no
UsePAM yes
```

ALSO

```
[gm-st01]~> cat /etc/pam.d/login | grep pam_motd
session    optional   pam_motd.so  motd=/run/motd.dynamic noupdate
session    optional   pam_motd.so
```

Maybe this also can be useful

```
[gm-st01]~> cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   gm-st01
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters

[gm-st01]~> cat /etc/hostname 
gm-st01.name.lab
```

Comment: The new thing about this is that when I remove centrifydc-openssh everything works perfectly, when Install it back then it brakes motd.

Comment: This looks strange to me: `127.0.1.1   gm-st01`. Isn't the local hostname usually a Real Ip Address?

Comment: So, this bug is really "`centrifydc-openssh` mishandles MOTD"? Why not ask whoever you got `centrifydc-openssh` from?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this with adding the following lint to /etc/pam.d/sshd

session    optional   pam_motd.so  motd=/run/motd.dynamic noupdate